# How to send data from one table to another in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem with send data from one table to another. I want delete data from first table too. Is it possible to do that operation under one button ? I have my records in table. I don't know how to route this operation.

This is my idea,but it didnt work. I get error Invalid route action

```
    public function dodaj($id)
{   
    $operacje = DB::table('operacja')->where('id',$id)->get();
    $operacje = DB::table('potwierdzona')->insert($operacje);
    $operacje = Operacja::findorFail($id);
    $operacje->delete();
    return redirect('patients');
}
```

My route is Route::post('potwierdzone/$id/dodaj/','PotwierdzonaController');

Answer (score 0):

you should use [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) and work with [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add an action to the route. The good practice is to use named routes:

```
Route::get('potwierdzone/{id}/dodaj', ['as' => 'dodaj', 'uses' => 'PotwierdzonaController@dodaj']);
```

And the `route()` helper to build links:

```
<a href="{{ route('dodaj', $propozycja->id) }}">
```

**Update**

Use this code to avoid other errors:

```
$operacje = Operacja::find($id);
Potwierdzona::create($operacje->toArray());
$operacje->delete();
return redirect('patients');
```

Comment: Its my button but I  still have  problem with routing  (NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php)           <td><a href="/potwierdzone/{{$propozycja -> id}}/dodaj/" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 40px;">Potwierdź Wizytę</a></td>

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski I've updated my answer. To avoid this kind of problems use named routes.

Comment: I've changed controller, for controller which return me all records.But it still doesnt working http://pastebin.com/rmFv6TS6 .

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski change route to `::get` since you're using simple `<a href` to build the link.

Comment: Now routing is good, but i have error - Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\strona\app\Http\Controllers\PropozycjasController.php on line 48

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski that's not how SO works. When you get an answer to the question, you should check the answer (and usually upvote too). And if you got another errors, you should create a new question. Please show me result of `dd($operacje->first());`. If it's an array, just use it without `->toArray()`

Comment: Use Eloquent instead of Query Builder. I've added code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, i will looking for help for next problem